# examples of working OR operators in varnish 4.1 VCL

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

Working on a varnish configuration with an ACL in it, and a section refers to the ipv4 wildcard to make sure the ip being matched is in the right format. however this is seemingly stripping out any ipv6 addresses, so we can't whitelist based on ipv6.

according to the varnish docs, the "||" operator should function as a logical OR so i should be able to allow things that either match 0.0.0.0 OR :: for an ipv6 wildcard.  however if i use the || operator, varnish won't restart and the varnish status specifically flags the || operator as the issue.

```
Aug 26 10:40:47 server17 varnishd[14748]: ('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 163 Pos 74)
Aug 26 10:40:47 server17 varnishd[14748]: if ((std.ip(req.http.X-Actual-IP,"0.0.0.0") !~ admin) && req.url ~ "^/") || if ((std.ip(req.http.X-Actu... "^/")  {
Aug 26 10:40:47 server17 varnishd[14748]: -------------------------------------------------------------------------##----------------------------...---------
Aug 26 10:40:47 server17 varnishd[14748]: Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2
```

this is just the latest one of the arrangements i have tried using the OR operator, but whether it's included inside the parentheses of the original query or not, the error always highlights this one operator

[image]

nowhere in the varnish docs do they give an actual example of the logical OR in use, so i am unsure how i'm using it incorrectly here. has it just been deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your use case to some extent, but the most important part about the VCL snippet below is the fact that the `||` operator is used.

Here's an example where an *acl* is matched, and where some other matches where done using an *or clause*.

```
vcl 4.1;
import std;

acl acl {
    "172.21.0.1";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.http.x-ip = std.ip(client.ip, "0.0.0.0");
    if ( std.ip(client.ip, "0.0.0.0") !~ acl || req.http.x-ip == "0.0.0.0" || req.http.x-ip == "::") {
        return(synth(403,"Forbidden for " + req.http.x-ip));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I will give this a try, I think part of the issue with the items i'm trying to use it for is the nesting. it also requires the ip to be pulled from the X-Forwarded-For header, as the site is behind cloudflare, so the req.http.X-Actual-IP has already been trimmed from something.